# How To Fix "The Debugger you selected cannot be started"

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I have an error with just-in-time debugger, when I try to start my app, it says "unknown exception" and gives me OK button. Now, After that I have 3 choices:
y'know the trio:

1. Solve and close the program
2. Close the program
3. Debug the program

If I click "Debug the program" [I see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXIEy.png)
Then, when I click YES, It says

> The debugger you selected cannot be started, choose another?

Since I don't have any other debuggers, I am stuck there until my death if I keep clicking yes buttons. So when I click no, it basically closes.
How do I debug this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as part of your post. Also, please reformat/edit your post to be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup `WinDBG` to be your `Just In Time` (JIT) debugger by running WinDBG.exe with command-line agument `-I` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638251/setup-windbg-as-default-debugger).
If you prefer `Visual Studio` as your JIT debugger you can set it up in `Tools|Options` menu as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kf6y2a(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: So, first second and first fail. How do I even run the winDBG, I am a noob at things like this.

Comment: WinDBG is best debugger in my opinion, but if you are new to this then this might take time, as WinDBG is quite a complex thing to learn. However, what about the second choice - setting up Visual-Studio for your JIT debbuger - did you try this?

Comment: Sorry, Im a bit late but, it says tools-Options menu, I really don't know what they mean by that, I mean what tools menu?

Comment: What they meant: open visual studio, go to Tools>Options>Debugging>Just-In-Time and set all three options (Managed, Native, Script). Unfortunately that does not solve the problem in my case, I still get the "The debugger cannot be started" message.