# Why is my windbg not in debugger list?

Tags: windows, windbg

I have installed my windbg as default debugger in command prompt with administrator rights.

Then I wrote a program that writes in null pointer so that it causes a crash.

After the crash, a window pops up and shows "debug" or "program close" options.

So I chose "debug", and got the window like the image I uploaded.

Q. Shouldn't it there be windbg for option?
Q. There gotta be something I have missed. Can you advice me to troubleshoot with windbg?

[image]

Comment: You need to register windbg as a [just-in-time debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That can be done by running `windbg.exe` with the `-I` switch command line switch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setup WinDbg as default debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638251/setup-windbg-as-default-debugger)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sean Cline suggested in his comment, you probably **haven't** set WinDbg to be the post-mortem debugger. If you had, WinDbg would launch rather than `vsjitdebugger.exe`.

Make sure you really ran `windbg.exe -I` from an elevated command prompt. Did you do that and got the following message box?

[image: WinDbg was successfully installed as the default postmortem debugger.]

*Edit:* Note that on a 64-bit Windows there are separate settings for post-mortem debugger for 64-bit applications and for WOW64 (32-bit) applications. Each version of WinDbg when receiving the `-I` flag sets itself as the post-mortem debugger **for its own bitness**. That is, running

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\windbg.exe" -I
```

will set `...\x64\windbg.exe` to be the post-mortem debugger for 64-bit applications but will leave `vsjitdebugger.exe` as the post-mortem debugger for WOW64 applications.

You can check the current configuration using the `REG QUERY` command. and your output should be something like this if you ran `windbg.exe -I`:

```
C:\Users\conio>reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug" /reg:64

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug
    UserDebuggerHotKey    REG_DWORD    0x0
    Debugger    REG_SZ    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\windbg.exe" -p %ld -e %ld -g
    Auto    REG_SZ    1
```

But it will probably be something like this if you just installed Visual Studio (and didn't run `windbg.exe -I`):

```
C:\Users\conio>reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug" /reg:32

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug
    UserDebuggerHotKey    REG_DWORD    0x0
    Debugger    REG_SZ    "C:\WINDOWS\system32\vsjitdebugger.exe" -p %ld -e %ld
```

(The `/reg:64` and `/reg:32` are required to get the "64-bit registry view" and the "32-bit registry view" respectively regardless of whether you're running `%WINDIR%\System32\REG.EXE` or `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\REG.EXE`. This obviously applies only to 64-bit Windows.)

Regarding your question: "*Shouldn't it there be windbg for option?*"

No. Look at the title. It says "***Visual Studio** Just-In-Time Debugger*". It's not a general utility to choose among different debuggers installed on your system. It just runs Visual Studio, but can choose whether to launch a new instance or use an existing one (and I think it lets you choose VS version if you have several versions installed).

Comment: You need to document that the 64-bit and the 32-bit registry key is important.  With the 32-bit key in Wow6432Node being most likely to be relevant.  Best to use Regedit.exe, the reg command doesn't help much.

Comment: You're right about the issue of separate debuggers for 64-bit and WOW64 applications, but the REG command supports working against the "32-bit view" of the registry (i.e. `KEY_WOW64_32KEY`) and that I didn't suggest using using the `REG` command to set the `AeDebug` value but rather only to view it. Setting with `windbg.exe -I` sets the right keys. But I'll add information, though you could have done it. It's a good point and a good edit. I would have approved it. :)